# How to convert font size to pixels?

Tags: sdl2

I'm trying to add text to my game using SDL_TTF, and it's working pretty well.

Except for one thing :

My text's SDL_Surface needs a width and a height, if I don't give it one it will automatically set it to 0, making the text invisible.

However, if I insert a value like 100 width and 100 height, it will stretch the image.

I need to know how I would convert ANY font size on the font **arial** to pixels in width and height.

Comment: The size of each font is different, I guess you only option is to try a size, get its width and height with `TTF_SizeText()` and then reduce it or increase it repeatedly

Comment: @Xriuk That would not give me a good high and width if the font size were to change during runtime though, right?

Comment: Are you using surfaces or textures for rendering?

Comment: @BiiX You could implement this into a function, and then call it whenever your font changes size

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 I'm using textures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, const char* text, {r, g, b});` renders a surface with text on it. You could just use something like

```
SDL_Surface* text = TTF_RenderText_Solid(arial, "hi", {r, g, b});
int textWidth = text->w;
int textHeight = text->h;
```

You don't even need to make a blank surface for this method.

Comment: That does not work, it gives me a height and width of 0.

Comment: Nevermind, it did work. I tried it before I asked the question and it didn't work... I must have done something really stupid. lol

Comment: No problem. Good luck with the project!